# How to store a pointer to a position inside char * buffer, sending to a function, retrieveing a value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a char * buffer in which I store any kind of values doing casting.  Every time I store a float I add 'len of var'  to 'my_position' var.

I need a way to access to the data from another point on my app.
Ok, buffer+position gives me the pointer to memory. How can I return it ? As an int ?
I think I have to return  a char * pointer. (pointer_char)

Ok, I have now this function :

```
 create_float(char * pointer_char) { 
 float * xx = reinterpret_cast<float*> (pointer_char);
}
```

I have a crash ....
Any help and suggestion would be appreciated ... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that I understood your question completely, but if you simply need a function that reads and returns a float value from a char* buffer, you can go with this:

```
float create_float(char* ptr)
{
   return *(reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr));
}
```

Also, it's difficult to tell the reason of the crash without some context. Can you post the code here?

Comment: the crash ocurrs becasue I dont retrieve a correct value... Is there any way to check that ptr is correct ? (that is to say, points to a right place ?) .

Comment: @tonnot: No, you have no way of knowing, which is why this sounds like a bad design.

Comment: I have an error on the buffer I'm using. Excuse me , close this. I start a new question.